# French equivalent of the English expression "you’re glued to the TV"

Tags: expressions

In English, when you are completely immersed/engrossed in an activity, to the point of being oblivious to everything else, you say "He can't tear/pull himself away from the TV", "He is glued to the TV", "He is locked/rooted in front of the TV" etc.

For what it's worth, we say in Japanese "釘付け {kugi-zuke}" with the literal meaning of "being fixed with nails to something" to express the idea of "your temporary excessive immersion in something".

I wonder, how would you express the same idea in French? For instance:

> "When not **locked in front of** a computer, she's **glued to** the viewfinder of her camera."
>
> "I finally managed to **tear/pull** my son **away from** the TV."
>
> "The book is so engagingly written it is hard to **put** it **down**."

Il se trouve que l'on emploie le verbe « riveted (by) » en anglais aussi pour désigner le fait de « se plonger complètement  dans une activité ». On peut donc utiliser les verbes « river / rivet / 釘付け » de la même façon, qui proviennent tous du nom « clou »  en trois langues différentes. Voici une coïncidence intéressante.

Comment: About nails, French has *il est cloué à son bureau* / *au lit*, but I wouldn't say *cloué à sa console de jeu* (but it would be understood).

Comment: *Docteur! Ma femme est clouée au lit! J'aimerais que vous la vissiez!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** : Just translate the expression literally, French has the same figurative meanings as English.

---

French has the same glue and metalwork ideas, in the form of scotch tape and rivets :

> Il est ***scotché** à la télé*
> Elle est ***rivée*** à son ordinateur (she's riveted)

These are maybe the most idiomatic expressions (but won't work with all things, e.g. I don't think you can be **rivée à la TV*). There are other variations based on glue (« *il passe son temps **le nez collé** à son écran* »).

Most importantly maybe, I find it hard to build a litteral translation from english figurative expressions that wouldn't be understood in french.
For instance, you can translate "tear/pull away" straightforwardly as « *arracher* », and it'll have the same figurative meaning in french.

> When not *locked* in front of a computer, she's *glued* to the viewfinder of her camera.
> Quand elle n'est pas **coincée** sur un ordinateur, on ne la **décolle** pas de son camescope.
> Quand elle n'est pas **verrouillée** à son ordinateur -- a bit strange, but will be understood
>
> I finally managed to *tear/pull* my son *away* from the TV.
> J'ai enfin réussi à **l'arracher** de la TV.
>
> The book is so engagingly written it is hard to *put it down*.
> Ce livre est tellement bien écrit qu'il est difficile à **déposer**.

Except "locked", all are very litteral translations, and they sound right in french to express the same idea. Admittedly I, as a native speaker, choose the "right" translations (e.g. « *elle est verrouillée à son ordinateur* » is not idiomatic, if straightforward to understand), but mostly they all seem to work, and everyone may prefer their own pet sayings.

Comment: Merci pour l'éclaircissement. Do you use "extirper" in any of these examples?

Comment: You could, in that "*extirper*" is synonym with "*arracher*". "*J'ai eu un mal fou à l'extirper de devant la TV.*" = I had a hard time pulling him away from the TV.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Very good answer, I disagree a bit about that I find idiomatic : the usage of *"coller"* ("Il a passé la journée collé à son ordi.") and adding some example in another answer.

Comment: I would better say "J'ai enfin réussi à l'arracher **à** la TV" or "l'arracher **de devant** la TV", and "verrouillée à son ordinateur" doesn't sound French at all.

Comment: @YohannV. **I'm glad you don't find the exact same expressions idiomatic. That's precisely the point of my answer.** There are no standard ways of saying this, so everyone has his pet expression, and others that he's not used to hearing (IMO).

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @NikanaReklawyks good answer, you can use

- [**river**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/river) (être rivé[e]) = put together metal pieces with [rivets](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rivet), and figuratively to keep eyes on.

  > When not locked in front of a computer, she's glued to the viewfinder of her camera.
  > Quand elle n'est pas rivée à son ordinateur, elle est collée à son camescope.
- [immerger](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/immerger) = submerge in liquid or [plonger](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plonger) = plunge into a liquid, both will have figuratively the sense of being immersed in an activity. 
  *With a more neutral meaning than those with lock or glue.*

  > Je me suis immergé dans ce livre et je n'ai pas vu le temps passer !
  > Quand on est plongé dans un film, on peut s'évader dans un nouveau monde.

Comment: +1 for ***"river"***, that one is quite idiomatic. That would be the best translation akin to the japanese nail expression OP mentions. Actually it's so good that I'm including it in my answer.